# Multichoicemode listener not working when onClicklistener added to listitem's child view

Tags: android, listview, multichoiceitems

I have added multichoice mode listener to my code:

```
   listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    listview.setMultiChoiceModeListener(this);
```

and my listview adpater getview code is:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
{
    final CustomObject customObject = arrayList.get(position);
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_pop_up2, parent, false);

        holder.txtCompanyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCompanyName);
        holder.txtProductName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtProductName);
        holder.imgBanner = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgBanner);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

        holder.txtCompanyName.setText(customObject.getCompanyName());
        holder.txtProductName.setText(customObject.getProductName());

        Glide.with(context).load(customObject.getImageUrl()).into(holder.imgBanner);

        holder.imgBanner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    return convertView;
}
```

now my problem is onClick of ImageView affect the multimodeListener of listview. beacuse of onClickListener on long press of imagr for multimode listener not working.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446249/enable-disable-item-selection-at-listview-in-multiple-choice-mode

Comment: If you are try for custom listview and want check boxes,
I had done the same yesterday,
The thing is When we need custom listview with checkboxes, we need to add checkbox in our custom row layout.
if we try to add

    listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

and also define custom list together, then it doesn't display checkboxes.